# Python class objectivity convention

Tags: python, class, coding-style

Is it a good style to create classes like that ? I read the PEP8 document but I didn't saw any good example. If not how is it a proper way ? Thanks for any answers.

```py
class Zone:
    def __init__(self, index=None, name=None):
        self._index = index
        self._name = name

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self._index

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @index.setter
    def index(self, index):
        self._index = index

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name
```

Comment: "Don't type if you don't need to"...

Comment: i use for check code pep8online.com/

Comment: Don't use properties. Just make the variable public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setters and getters don't do anything. With your implementation, the user of this class does this:

```
z = Zone()
z.name = 'foo'
print(z.name)
```

Compare to this implementation:

```
class Zone:
    def __init__(self, index=None, name=None):
        self.index = index
        self.name = name


z = Zone()
z.name = 'foo'
print(z.name)
```

It works exactly the same with a lot less code.

Unless you *do* anything in your setters and/or getters, you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

If what you intend doing is encapsulating your data and setting it with setters and getting it with getters, then what you did will not be helpful. you declared the _name and _index as protected, it does not mean it cannot be accessed by extenal functions, so functions outside the class can easily access and change them, making your getter and setter to be useless.

However, you can declare them as private by using one additional underscore in front, so that your property class will be removed and then the setters class will be useful, it will no longer be accessed by external functions.

```
class Zone:
    def __init__(self,index=None,name=None):
        self.__index = index
        self.__name = name

    def index(self, index):
        self.__index = index

    def name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name


zone=Zone()

zone.name('ben')

print(zone.get_name())
>>>ben
print(zone.__name)

>>> AttributeError: 'Zone' object has no attribute '__name'
```